# How to set ACCELERATE interpolator for AnimatorValue object in harmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am porting one open sources library from Android to HarmonyOS where I have to set ACCELERATE interpolator for AnimatorValue object. The same thing in android using ValueAnimator object is done as below

```
ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

How do I do this in harmonyOS?

Answer (score 1):

**CurveTypes** are Harmony alternatives for Android **Interpolators**. Example Usage,

```java
    AnimatorValue animator = new AnimatorValue();
    animator.setCurveType(Animator.CurveType.ACCELERATE);
```